# Xampp auto killed on installation?

Tags: php, installation, xampp

I'm trying to install Xampp on CentOS 6.4 but this doesn't let me continue!

This is the output:

```
[root@imperius ~]# ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Welcome to the XAMPP Setup Wizard.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select the components you want to install; clear the components you do not want
to install. Click Next when you are ready to continue.

XAMPP Core Files : Y (Cannot be edited)

XAMPP Developer Files [Y/n] :y

Is the selection above correct? [Y/n]: y

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installation Directory

XAMPP will be installed to /opt/lampp
Press [Enter] to continue:

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Setup is now ready to begin installing XAMPP on your computer.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: y

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please wait while Setup installs XAMPP on your computer.

 Installing
 0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
 ####Killed
[root@imperius ~]#
```

Obviously the command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp` doesn't work because it doesn't complete the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your installation process was killed by Out-Of-Memory Killer:

```
grep -i kill /var/log/messages*
```

My issue finally gone away after I added a SWAP file to my linux.

Answer (score 12):

I have also encountered the same problem . i think it is not enough swap space.You can do this as follows：

```
    1. sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1024 count=2000000
    2. sudo mkswap -f  swapfile
    3. sudo swapon swapfile
```

Comment: its working thnk you

Answer (score 3):

In my case, at least, it was just a lack of memory. 512MB seems not enough to install XAMMP. I managed to finish the installation upgrading RAM to 1GB.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and we solved it by updating the memory from 512M to 1G.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: Yes but it don't recognize the command, I also tried "sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start" with no luck, it throws routes to unavailable files due to the failed installation

Comment: What was your source for xampp? Download, repository?

Comment: Downloaded from the official page and installed by the instructions of the page

Comment: Did you add the correct permissions? # chmod +x  xampp-linux-x64.5.6-0-installer.run
# ./xampp-linux-x64.5.6-0-installer.run

Comment: Granted, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I tested this now. It works.

1. sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1024 count=2000000
2. sudo mkswap -f  swapfile
3. sudo swapon swapfile